# Textarea does not stop making new line when Enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i don't understand why my textarea won't stop making new lines and won't call function when enter is pressed depsite the fact jquery is to do so. With input it's working ok. And yes i still want that Submit button there.

JavaScript

```
function da(){

$('#com').unbind('keypress').bind('keypress', function(e){
   var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if(code == 13) // Enter key is pressed
   {  e.preventDefault();
      chat();
   }
});
}
```

HTML

```
<form id='com' method='post'>


Mesaj:<br>
<textarea name='mesaj' rows='7' col='60'></textarea><br/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='Trimite mesaj!' onclick='chat()'>

</form>"
```

Comment: At least the native `keypress` is not cancelable, try `keydown` instead. Notice, that you don't need to try to detect `keyCode` in jQuery, it's normalized, and is just `which` in any browser.

Comment: What code is in your chat() function ?

Comment: @Teemu *`and is just keyCode in any browser`*... you mean `e.which`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yep, corrected the comment.

Comment: @PhilipG it's irrelevant i can put there an alert to see if it's working. Is a function that send the form that to another php file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To stop newlines (along with carriage return), you need to capture `10` as well as `13` on `keypress` using `keycode`.

***See this snippet:***

```js
$("textarea").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        chat();
    }
});

function chat() {
    alert("hello chat");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name='mesaj' rows='7' col='60'></textarea><br/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='Trimite mesaj!' onclick='chat()' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this check my code and sample example for your reference

```js
$(".Post_Description_Text").keydown(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
  e.preventDefault();
       }
 });
```

```css
.Post_Description_Text{ 
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text"  class="Post_Description_Text" rows="5"></textarea>
 <button id="check_btn">click here to check</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

HTML(add `id` to your textarea):

```
<form id='com' method='post'>
    Mesaj:<br>
    <textarea name='mesaj' id="mesaj" rows='7' col='60'></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='Trimite mesaj!' onclick='chat()'/>
</form>
```

JS(avoid new lines when enter key is pressed):

```
$('#mesaj').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        chat();
    }
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/p3ufLjoe/