# how to make textarea not start a new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to make to make textareas not start a new line each time I click on enter I need to do this with javascript not Jquery

```
event.prevent Default();
```

so I need an alternative
                                                       Thankyou

Comment: What have you tryed so far?

Comment: What is the purpose of this effort?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textarea won't stop making new line when Enter is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975349/textarea-wont-stop-making-new-line-when-enter-is-pressed)

Comment: I have tried `document.getElementById('textarea').onkeypress = function(e) { 
        if(e.which== 13){
           e.preventDefault();
        }
};` and the purpose of this effort is making a non-Jquery chat-box and George I wanted a non-Jquery code ur example has jquery( I didn't know preventDefault() was a javascript function not a Jquery one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you want to prevent the default action of 'enter' on the textarea so :

HTML code:

```
<textarea id="textarea" onkeyup="function()"></textarea>
```

Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').onkeypress = function(e) { 
        if(e.which== 13){
           e.preventDefault();
        }
};
```

jQuery:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e){

    if(e.Which == 13){
      e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

The "e.which == 13" checks if enter is pressed, and prevents the default action (which was previously a carriage return).

Comment: "I need to do this with javascript not Jquery"

Comment: Yeah i used the same code as above but i want to do this without requiring Jquery i need to do this with plain javascript thank you for the answer tho

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
 function preventEnter(evt) {
     if(evt.Which == 13){
         evt.preventDefault();
     }
 }

 document.getElementById('my-textarea').addEventListener(
     'keypress', preventEnter, false
 );
```

Comment: Don't forget to validate my answer please :)

Comment: But the guy above got the got first and answered first your code solved my problem thank you (I really mean it ) but the other guy answered first I guess its only fair to validate hes answer as it seems I can only validate one answer sorry :'(

Answer (score 0):

use css [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: It's already solved and I think you didn't understand my question (sorry bad grammar ) thanks for the answer tho appreciate it